# Two UpdatePanels working in parallel, one not updating

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have two update panels (lets call them A and B). In A, I have a simple checkbox. AutoPostback set to true. When you check it (or uncheck it), it will enable/disable a simple dropdown within the same UpdatePanel.

UpdatePanel B has a long running process in it. It fires off a request for a dropdown to be created that takes nearly 2 minutes to construct. If I load the page and don't touch anything, the dropdown is constructed after about 2 minutes and renders perfectly. However, if during that two minutes I decide to check my checkbox (and cause a partial postback for panel A), updatepanel B never gets rendered. While debugging, I found that it is completing its retrieval successfully, but the actual panel never refreshes to show the control.

I have tried using UpdateMode = Conditional on panel B (to ensure it would not be disturbed by panel A) and it produces the same results. I have verified that B.Update() is being called also.

**EDIT**

Panel A:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMailScrub" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAnalyzeLaunch" runat="server" onclick="btnAnalyzeLaunch_Click" Text="Analyze Launch" style="display: none" />    
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:CheckBox ID="cbxScrub" runat="server" Checked="true" 
                        oncheckedchanged="cbxScrub_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" /></td><td><label for="cbxScrub">Scrub this campaign</label></td>
                <td style="padding-left: 10px">
                    Vendor:&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlScrubVendor" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="LexisNexis" Value="LexisNexis" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Panel B:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDdlCampaigns" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAnalyzeLaunch" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField id="hidAction" runat="server" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPleaseWait" runat="server"><img src="style/images/PleaseWait.gif" />&nbsp;Please wait while the Five9 Campaigns are retrieved...</asp:Panel>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCampaigns" Visible="false" runat="server" class="required"
            AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCampaigns_SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnRefreshDDL" runat="server" onclick="btnRefreshDDL_Click" style="display: none" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You ask too much from UpdatePanel :)**

**UpdatePanel can not work with 2 parallel request that way**. Consider to make some ajax call to get your results.

**Why you may ask, one basic reason is that every page have only one viewstate.** When you ask from the A or the B, UpdatePanel to send/get data, then the viewstate must change to a new viewstate. Now, when you ask a result from A, and before you end, you ask results from B, you going to get 2 different viewstate, and one of them is going to fail because in the middle time have change.

ViewState is not the only think, in every update panel click, **the page post back all inputs post to page, both A and B inputs and all the rest inside the page**, this is also a problem. Imaging this for example, you trigger A UpdatePanel with inputs A+B, and then before the A ends, you trigger B UpdatePanel with the same inputs. Now A, waits for results from A+B, the same and B, but in the middle time the A+B results from A is now different because B has change them - and fails.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Due to the simplicity of Panel A, I'm going to control that via Javascript; its just hide/show and enable/disable. Nothing really heavy there. I will keep my long running process as the only updatepanel on the page and I am confident that it will work.